# Are defaultProps mandatory when using Redux connect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-proptypes

Let's say, we have a simple React component connected with Redux:

```
const MyComponent = ({ name }) => <p>{name}</p>

// PropTypes definition - we'll back to that in a moment...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  name: state.name,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

And here is the question - is it mandatory to specify the `defaultProps` for `MyComponent` when connecting it to the Redux store? As below:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  name: 'hsz',
}
```

Or maybe we're safe and there is no requirement to specify `defaultProps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, use of React's `PropTypes` and `defaultProps` is *never* mandatory.  However, if there's a possibility that a prop may not actually exist or be `undefined`, then you should handle that case in some way.  This can be done by defining a `defaultProps` value, using destructuring defaults in `render()`, or at least checking to see if there's a meaningful value for that prop before trying to render based on its value.

For some more advice on this topic, see Dave Ceddia's post [Watch Out for Undefined State](https://daveceddia.com/watch-out-for-undefined-state/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are required to specify defaultProps. The props are carried from the mapStateToProps the way you set up your "name: state.name". If you just pull in "state" then you would need to call this.props.state.name. I think you'll need to call this.props.name instead of just name there.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultProps` is never mandatory.

But is a good practice for a component to declare `PropTypes` for the reader to know the props needed or required by this component.

For all props defined in `PropTypes` specified as **not** `isRequired`,
then these props should be defined in `defaultProps` for their default value.